# How to enquote string in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

`dbms_assert.enquote_literal` is used to single quote a string in Oracle. Is there any similar function in MySQL and PHP?

Comment: Yes there is `real_escape_string`, but what are you really trying to do? Quoting strings usually means you are trying to do some validation/injection prevention and a better bet might be to use prepared statements.

Comment: I only need for quoting string with single quote through built-in function.

Comment: I understand, but what are you *really* trying to do. *Why* do you want to escape the string? Refer to this: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is [`QUOTE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_quote) in MySQL.

If you want to escape quotes from PHP then you don't need any escaping mechanism because PHP has prepared statements that can bind the data separately from SQL.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a custom function for that

example:

```
function str_enq($string = '')
{
    $char = '\'';
    return str_pad($string, strlen($string) + 2, $char, STR_PAD_BOTH);
}
```

Comment: You just described `'\'' + $string + '\''`. Which isn't escaping.